# SQLite ClassNotFound on Ubuntu

Tags: java, sqlite, ubuntu-13.10

After program compiling with

```
java -cp .:jsoup-1.8.1.jar:sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar:. Client.java
```

I'm trying to run with (from folder one level above)

```
java work.Client
```

and I'm getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

Here's my connection method

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
}
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
```

On Windows (Eclipse) everything is working fine. What should I do?

Comment: maybe it isnt in your classpath?

Comment: Question may be dumb but, how to add it?

Comment: As you have already used `-cp`. `.` indicate it is in current directory. so check is `jsoup-1.8.1` and `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar` jars are located where you try to execute `java` command.